Can't add plugins to Squash Docker
I use Squash with his docker image (squashtest/squash). I want to add plugins so I add the start-plugins.cfg with the name of plugins in. When I start the docker he crash after told me :
2024-05-17 16:30:38 **Starting plugins on boot**
2024-05-17 16:30:38 
2024-05-17 16:30:38 --> Found start-plugins.cfg file. Parsing through it to find the plugins:
2024-05-17 16:30:38 result-publisher
 does not exist or wrong name. Stop the process
*: No such file or directorypt/squash-tm/plugin-files/result-publisher

Can someone help me please ?
Here is my docker-compose :
version: '3.8'

services:
  squash-tm-pg:
    container_name: squash-tm-pg
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - ./db-postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      squash-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2

  squash:
    depends_on:
      - squash-tm-pg
    environment:
      SQTM_DB_TYPE: ${DB_TYPE}
      SQTM_DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SQTM_DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      SQTM_DB_NAME: ${DB_DATABASE}
      SQTM_DB_HOST: 172.20.0.2
      TZ: Europe/Paris
    ports:
      - 8181:8080/tcp
    image: squashtest/squash
    links:
      - squash-tm-pg:postgres
    volumes:
      - ./squash-tm-logs:/opt/squash-tm/logs
      - ./conf/start-plugins.cfg:/opt/squash-tm/conf/start-plugins.cfg
    networks:
      squash-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3

  squash-orchestrator:
    depends_on:
      - squash
    environment:
      SQUASH_TM_URL: http://localhost:8181/squash/
    image: squashtest/squash-orchestrator
    volumes:
      - ./squash-orchestrator-logs:/opt/squash-orchestrator/logs
    networks:
      squash-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.4

  postman-newman:
    build: .
    command: run /etc/newman/Rapports_Squash.postman_collection.json --environment /etc/newman/Rapports_Squash.postman_collection.json --reporters cli,html
    volumes:
      - ./tests/postman:/etc/newman
    networks:
      squash-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
   
networks:
  squash-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16

volumes:
  squash-tm-logs:
  squash-orchestrator-logs:


The start-plugins.cfg :
#### Autom-DevOps ####
result-publisher
squashautom-community
testplan-retriever-community
scm-git

#### Bugtracker ####
bugzilla
gitlab

#### Report ####
report-books-pdf

#### Sync ####
xsquash4gitlab

I want to add plugins to use GitLab with Squash
